# What is this right-arrow line symbol in the iOS simulator?

Tags: shortcut, xcode-simulator

The iOS simulator sometimes shows me a keyboard shortcut helper when I spam <kbd>Command-Shift-H</kbd> in an attempt to close an app, and one of the shortcuts (the one I need) includes this symbol, but I don't know what key it refers to.

[image: right-arrow line symbol]

What key is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a tab character. See this meta answer for details:

- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/690/5472

The main list of keys is at [Keyboard icons & terminology](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/keyboard-icons-terminology)

Comment: The shortcut shown in the simulator is `command ->|` for "Switch App", so tab makes sense, but why would they show OSX shortcuts in the iOS simulator?

Comment: Seems odd to me at first as well, then again the iPad Pro and other iOS devices support various keyboards, so it could be part of iOS and it’s certainly something on macOS /  would expect a keyboard with a tab to switch apps.

Comment: @SimpleJ Command-Tab with an external keyboard connected on the iPad switches apps as you would expect.